# Error syntax laravel 5.7 maatwebsite/excel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to use maatwebsite/excel on laravel 5.7 and I'm currently stuck for some time on a syntax error, can you help me?

"syntax error, unexpected '}'" line 28 :

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Excel;

class ExportExcelController extends Controller
{
    function Export()
    {
      $customer_data = DB::table('qualys')->get();
      return view('export_excel')->with('customer_data', $customer_data);
    }
    function excel()
    {
      $customer_data = DB::table('qualys')->get()->toArray();
      $customer_data[] = array('qid','ip');

      foreach($customer_data as $customer)
      {
         $customer_array[] = array(
                  'qid' => $customer -> qid,
                  'ip' => $customer -> ip
        )
      }
      Excel::create('customer data', function($excel) use ($customer_array)
      {
           $excel->setTitle('customer Data');
           $excel->sheet('Customer Data', function($sheet) use ($customer_array)
           {
             $sheet->fromeArray($customer_array, null, 'A1', false, false);
           });
      })->download('xlsx');
    }
}
```

Sincerely

Comment: You have forgot semicolon on ```line 26``` after  ```)```.```$customer_array[] = array(
                  'qid' => $customer -> qid,
                  'ip' => $customer -> ip
        );```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cause lies in your variables in the `foreach`. There should not be a space between object and property, like this:

```
$customer_array[] = array(
    'qid' => $customer->qid,
    'ip' => $customer->ip
);
```

(Note the semicolon at the end)

Answer (score 0):

you should update your excel function code like:

```
   function excel()
{
  $customer_data = DB::table('qualys')->get()->toArray();
  $customer_data[] = array('qid','ip');

  foreach($customer_data as $customer)
  {
     $customer_array[] = array(
              'qid' => $customer -> qid,
              'ip' => $customer -> ip
    );
  }
```

Comment: @M.Hemart: glad to help :) and if my answer work for you then please accept my answer